# R Generate Bounded Random Sample Arround Specific Mean

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability

I've been stuck with this for a while, so I decided to write a question.

**Problem:** How to generate a random sample (of lenght n) with a *lower/upper* bound and arround a specific *mean*.

Observation: distribution doesn't need to be specific (it could be normal, beta, etc).

**Aproaches considered:**

- One aproach is to use the `rtnorm` function [(package msm)](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/msm/html/tnorm.html) which generates a random numbers with a normal distribution within specified bounds but it doesn't hold your wanted mean value.
- A second aproach I've tried is this function which I found in a question I can't find anymore

  ```
  rBootstrap <- function(n, mean, sd, lowerBound, upperBound){
    range <- upperBound - lowerBound
    m <- (mean-lowerBound) / range #mapping mean to 0-1 range
    s <- sd / range #mapping sd to 0-1 range
    a <- (m^2 - m^3 - m*s^2)/s^2 #calculating alpha for rbeta 
    b <- (m-2*m^2+m^3-s^2+m*s^2)/s^2 #calculating beta for rbeta
    data <- rbeta(n,a,b)  #generating data
    data <- lowerBound + data * range #remaping to given bounds
    return(data)
  }
  ```

  this function actually gives great results unless: **upperBound > lowerBound + (2* mean - lowerBound)** (upper bound exceeds two times the distance from the lowerBound to the mean).

Particularly, I would like to generate a random sample of lenght 1,800, with values between 50,000 and 250,000 with mean value = 70,000.

Comment: What distribution do you want your random sample to be generated from? This link could help: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-generate-a-normal-distribution-with-mean-1-min-0-2-max-0-8-td3481450.html

Comment: Thank you @Chrisss ,I gave the observation that I'm not looking for a specific distribution, although all the research I made was oriented to normal and beta, I beleive one of this two could give a good aproach just by observing their density function shape.

Comment: BTW, what sigma do you want? Again, do you want formula sigma or observable sigma? I'm flying in two hours, but as soon as I get back, I'll try to write some **R**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use truncated normal distribution, but `mean` should be recalibrated. If you look at `mean` in `rtnorm`, it is clearly stated: `mean` is the mean of the original Normal distribution before truncation.

If you want OBSERVABLE mean to be equal to desired value, just use formula from [Truncated Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution):

```
mu = E + sigma*(f(b) - f(a))/(F(b) - F(a))
```

Here `E` is what mean value you want to have (70,000 in your case), `f(x)` being gaussian density, `F(x)` being cumulative function, `a` and `b` being interval boundaries (centered and scaled).

```
a = (LB - mu)/sigma
b = (RB - mu)/sigma
```

After you computed `mu`, pass it down to rtnorm as `mean` parameter.

NB: you might want to do similar exercise with `sigma` - what's going into rtnorm is NOT what you're going to observe in sampling, see again wiki reference

UPDATE

Ok, got to the code myself, though first cut is done in Python (looking into **R**) right now. Problem is, for given observable mean `mu` is in `f(a)`, in `f(b)`, in `F(a)` and in `F(b)` which converts the problem into search of the root of the non-linear equation. But it is solvable, please check the [code](https://github.com/Kri-Ol/Truncated-Gauss). Note, it follows pretty much wiki notation.

For example for your parameters and sigma=12,000, I got

```
Found mu = 68430.372119287 for the desired mean 70000.0 and sigma 12000.0
Sampled 100000 truncated gaussians and got observed mean = 70023.15990337673
```

For your parameters and sigma=24,000, I got

```
Found mu = 52275.475000378945 for the desired mean 70000.0 and sigma 24000.0
Sampled 100000 truncated gaussians and got observed mean = 69922.16000288539
```

So `mu` is getting pretty close to the left boundary for large `sigma`, which is expected behavior, but observed mean stays close to 70,000, which is what you want.

UPDATE II

Here is **R** code, in github repo as well

```
require(rootSolve)
require(msm)

phi <- function(z) {
    dnorm(z)
}

Phi <- function(z) {
    pnorm(z)
}

Mean <- function(mu, sigma, a, b) {
    alfa <-  (a - mu) / sigma
    beta <-  (b - mu) / sigma

    Z <-  Phi(beta) - Phi(alfa)

    mu + sigma*(phi(alfa) - phi(beta))/Z
}

f <- function(mu, mean, sigma, a, b) {
    mean - Mean(mu, sigma, a, b)
}

a <-  50000.0
b <-  250000.0
mean  <- 70000.0
sigma <- 24000.0

# find mu for desired mean
q <- uniroot(f, c(a, b), mean, sigma, a, b)
mu <- q$root

print(sprintf("Found mu = %f for the desired mean %f and sigma %f", mu, mean, sigma))

# sampling test
set.seed(32345)
N = 100000
r <- rtnorm(N, mean=mu, sd=sigma, lower=a, upper=b)

print(sprintf("Sampled %d truncated gaussians and got observed mean = %f", N, mean(r)))
```

Comment: Thank you, in this case f(a) would be my desired lowerBound? if so F(a)=0, viceversa for f(b) and F(b)=1?

Comment: @AlfredoLozano I've updated wrt `a` and `b`. No, If you look at wiki, `\phi(x)` is pure gauss, and `\Phi(x)` is cumulative for that gauss (variation of error function), so F(a) is not 0 and F(b) is not 1

Comment: @AlfredoLozano You have to have some value for sigma - and, what's important, if you want it to be FORMULA sigma or OBSERVABLE sigma.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help.
I don't have a specific sigma which I would like to see, all I need is the sample to be bounded and hold OBSERVABLE desired mean. Any sigma that achieves this is ok, problem is I don't see which sigma is even suitable.

Comment: I have wrote your answer in code (with sigma still not figured out), so far, small values of sigma tend to group the whole sample arround the OVSERBABLE desired mean and do not achieve the bounds, large values of sigma achieve the lower/upper bounds but do not meet OBSERVABLE desired mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this particular aproach does not acomplish the desired upper bound. Curiously(to me), it gives the exact same result as the one obtained from fiting a beta distribution like on the code I posted.

Comment: @AlfredoLozano What do you mean ` does not acomplish the desired upper bound` ? If you sample long enough and set sigma large enough, you'll get close to upper bound. Say, for seed 12345 after 10^6 samples I got max value at ~190,000.

Comment: @AlfredoLozano I ran your code with sigma=12,000, got max sampled value from 10^6 samples about 162,000. So, what's the difference? Though I tend to agree binomial would have fatter tail

Comment: I now realize that was not a good translation, all I mean is, a solution to this problem should be able to generate a random sample of lenght n with specified: lower/upper bound and observable mean.

Comment: @AlfredoLozano As far as I can see truncated gaussian (and beta distribution) do the trick: mean is pretty close to desired, all sampled values are within the range. To me it looks like you have requirement which is not spelled out...

Comment: You are right about that, I now think maybe question is missing that I would like some of the generated values to meet the upper bound

Comment: @AlfredoLozano Ok, that I finally got. But it is random sampling, so values would never be exactly at the upper bound. And definitely you want something with fatter right tail than gaussian. Beta might work, but I would also advice to take a look at right-truncated Gamma distribution: http://www.m-hikari.com/astp/astp2013/astp21-24-2013/zaninettiASTP21-24-2013.pdf